# Change Position of Recently Viewed Products

Tags: magento2, product

I have added a widget of recently viewed products in Magento 2.3.5
On the product view page, recently viewed products display before related products.
How to change the layout and show recently viewed products after related and upsell products?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a way for it. You should call widget in one cms block like this - https://prnt.sc/y0ne5a

After that in your catalog_product_view.xml file you need to call this cms block like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content.aside">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="widget_block" after="-">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">widget_block</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

AS per above code recently products view block will be displayed after related/upsell products.